# How to upload an image to a node server endpoint using pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, upload

I'm trying to create a small service that converts images from one type to another.
I'll get to the conversion part later, right now i cant even send it to the node server properly.

i have a simple script that's supposed to use filesystem to read an image and then POST it to a node server endpoint.

I couldn't find a way to do this anywhere online

i tried all kinds of different ways and formats, but on the endpoint the req.body is always an empty object or just an error

```
const fse = require('fs-extra');


var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();





fse.readFile('testimg.png', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err
    }
    console.log(data)
    xhr.open("POST", 'http://localhost:3000/convert', true); // true for asynchronous 

    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/upload');






    xhr.send(data)

})

and this is the server endpoint:

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();




router.get('/', (req,res)=>{
  res.send("hello")
})

router.post('/', async(req,res)=>{


  console.log(req.body);

  res.send("Hello i work")
})


module.exports = router;
```

What i want is to get the data on the server endpoint and to be able to process it and convert it for example: upload jpg and convert and send back as png or the opposite.

Help highly appreciated

Comment: Could it be because you're sending the request to http://localhost:3000/convert and there's no /convert in your router? Try to change the router.post("/".... to router.post("/convert"....

Comment: Oh thanks for the answer but that's not it, i named it /convert in the app.js so in the router its just '/'

Comment: If I'm not wrong, there's no body property within the request object by default. Not sure if that has changed recently but you may use body-parser. I don't know if this could help you but you can take a look at: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html

Comment: Btw, I'm assuming that you're using different NodeJS applications, and you're first running your server and then you're sending the request right?

Comment: I'm looking into this right now, will update if it solves, thanks

Comment: Hi @lucaswerner yes i am running two different instances. i read the article you linked but its doing get requests which aren't as relevant, im trying to post an image using a javascript file to a node server